# How to get the bounding box (MultiPolygon) of a geographic region?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, google-cloud

I need to execute a BigQuery database query whereby I'm trying to ascertain if a given lat, lon coordinate is within one of a few US counties.

One of those counties is Collin County in Texas, shown here in [Google Maps](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Collin+County,+TX,+USA/@33.1934271,-96.7096027,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x864c48a7ddbb79f9:0x4bcefe1534feb686!8m2!3d33.1795213!4d-96.4929797):

[image: Collin County, TX, USA]

BigQuery [supports GIS functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions) I'd need like [`ST_CONTAINS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_contains), but I can't figure out how to get, say, a GeoJSON representation of that polygon Google Maps is showing from either that service or OpenStreetMap.

The closest I've gotten with OpenStreetMap + Overpass is the following query:

```
[out:json][timeout:180];
relation(1837688);
out geom;
```

But the polygon I try to create from that response using `members` doesn't line up with what OpenStreetView has https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1837688.

[image: OpenStreetMap's Collin County]

[image: My Collin County]

Is there a more general solution I can use to create these bounding polygons for a region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery has a few public datasets, including US counties, that you can directly use.

```
SELECT geo_id, state_fips_code, county_name, county_geom 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.counties` 
WHERE county_name LIKE '%Collin%'
```

This returns two counties, the one with geo_id = 48085 seems what you need. Here it is in [BigQuery GeoViz](https://bigquerygeoviz.appspot.com/):

[image]

Comment:  that's amazing! Thank you very much!